# c++ from javascript

Tags: javascript, c++

I need to call a c++ function from the javascript. 
Please somebody hlp..

Comment: Javascript running in the browser?  Javascript running on the web server?  Please be more specific.

Comment: and perhaps also state what you're actually trying to do. The solution might not involve c++ (or javascript) at all.

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about a web browser, then running native code from Javascript is usually done by exposing the necessary functions through a web browser plugin. Different web browsers have different ways to write plugins; Firefox and Chrome use NPAPI whereas Internet Explorer uses ActiveX.

There is an open source project called Firebreath which makes it really easy to write cross-platform browser plugins which work on both NPAPI and ActiveX hosts.

http://www.firebreath.org

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at WebKit/Qt (assuming you are interested in writing a browser that exports additional features to the JavaScript - special hardware-related API and the likes)

Comment: +1 Very good answer. That's the first thing that popped into my head too.

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke any c++ function after compiling it into dll using javascript by extending Activex Object

like

var myNativeObj= new ActiveXObject("foo.dll");

myNativeObj.someMethod();//Some Method is defined in class

but this is restricted to Internet Explorer browser alone.

Comment: then how to compile a class to dll, please give a step to step example or a link to better tutorial. Its first time I'm working with this kind..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: If you are using VisualC++ you have options creating for DLL within the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

You can write browser extension and use it from javascript code.

[NPAPI in Chrome](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html), [NPAPI in Mozilla/Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Plugins)

Answer (score 0):

In IE, you can use ActiveX.
In Firefox, you can use js-ctypes: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Jsctypes/api
In Chrome, I'm not sure, V8 maybe have a support.